# Word that would mean "to make a narrative out of"

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, word-choice, phrases, narration

I have a question about a potential word that may or may not exist.

I'm trying to find a word that would basically mean something like "to make a story out of" or turn into a narrative.... like, i think I'm trying to say.... like, to turn ostensibly unconnected events into a trajectory of some sort. to connect them and make a story out of them. What would be a word for that please?

I don't know if one even exists for this. If I had to make up a word to perhaps give better insight as to what I mean I suppose I would say something along the lines of.... to "narracize" or to "storyicize" does that make it any clearer?

Thank you regardless!:)

Comment: My first thought is yarn, as in: verb (used without object)
Informal. to spin a yarn; tell stories

Comment: Could use it as such, "he could yarn any old situation into a fantastic story."

Comment: How about "narrate"?

Comment: Are the story details and their connection factual or is the whole thing ***concocted***?

Comment: I agree with @HotLicks ... "narrate".

Comment: 'Narrativise/ze' is given by [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/narrativize#English), but it seems quite rare (not in many other online dictionaries). But it can be found by a simple and obvious search.

Comment: _Narrate_ is what you're doing; it means tell a story in temporal "and then" order. _Narrative_ is the result, and _narratizing_ is one of several causative verbs one might use, rather like _weaponize_, which has a certain recent currency.

Answer (score 2):

**Storyweaving** appears to be a neologism of *weaving a story*, which is more common.

> Storyweaving determines how the illustrated story points will be revealed or unfolded to the audience.

[Dramatica, not a dictionary](https://dramatica.com/dictionary/storyweaving)

The same source also defines *storyencoding*.

> Storyencoding turns raw story points into specific scenarios, events, and dialog.

To me storyencoding has a jargon sound and loses the connection to *weaving a story*, which I imagine most readers would recognize as in *storyweaving*.

Comment: Yes, I'd say _storyweaving_ has enough currency (and it's easily transparent enough) to qualify as a neologism, a new word, rather than a DIY effort. ... weave a story out of ... is needed for a transitive usage, but OP _does_ add the 'phrases' tag.

Comment: Using weaving metaphors for stories is older than writing, which uses the same metaphors.

Answer (score 1):

**storify** transitive verb

> Definition: to narrate or describe in story
> History and Etymology: STORY entry 1 + *-fy*
> [[Merriam-Webster]](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/storify#:%7E:text=%3A%20to%20narrate%20or%20describe%20in%20story)

**Storify** also had a social media definition:

> to use the social networking service Storify to create stories or
> timelines using social media such as Twitter, Facebook and Instagram
>
> *She asked him to clarify his comments but he stood by them. She has storified this on Twitter.*
>
> [[Macmillan]](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/storify)

The service "Storify was shut down on May 16, 2018." [[Wikipedia]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Storify)

Note: Due to the popularity of the now defunct service, Storify, most usage examples of the verb *storify* will not be found in the top results.

Example of usage (defined in text):

> Storify: Make science tell a story.
> 6/3/2013
>
> Elsewhere I have written about the potential power of narrative to
> help students understand and remember complex subject matter
> (Willingham, 2004; 2009). Now a new study (Arya & Maul, 2012) provides
> fresh evidence that putting to-be-learned material in a story format
> improves learning outcomes.
>
> —Daniel Willingham [[Science & Education Blog]](http://www.danielwillingham.com/daniel-willingham-science-and-education-blog)

Herein, a link to other examples gathered by [WordSense](https://www.wordsense.eu/storified/).

Comment: The FreeDictionary only cites Webster's [1913] for this word (_storify_), so I'm guessing it's at best archaic in the 'make into a story' sense.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth - See under 'Practical examples' here, if we can use any sort of "dictionary" (https://www.wordsense.eu/storified/). But the proper suffix would be *-fy* (not *cize*).

Comment: It is certainly still used, as well as being in Merriam-Webster and [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/storify) (which cites a 2014 example). There was a social media site called Storify, and uses such as [this](https://www.nationaltheatrescotland.com/storify) and [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.storify.sharingapp&hl=en_GB&gl=US).

Comment: Yes, the examples certainly add weight.

Answer (score 1):

Serialize may be suitable.

"*After hearing about a pattern of mysterious fires, two journalists serialized the events into a coherent timeline and published a sensationalist article about rogue arsonists.*"

I would expect to read *compose a narrative* or *fabricate a narrative*.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).